# Remove 2 different object types from canvas with mouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf

So i've got 2 types of object to place on my canvas: Rectangles and Textboxes. **My problem is as follow**: I need to remove with Mousedown the rectangles and textboxes like an eraser. I can remove only a rectangle if I only place rectangles on my screen, I can remove only a textbox if I only place a textbox on my screen. But I need to remove them both on my screen with `Mousedown` (mouse) so for **example**: on my screen they are 2 rectangles and 1 `textbox`, I click on them and got the follow **error**: 
Cannot convert an object of type System.Windows.Controls.TextBox into a type of System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle

I know it's a casting problem, but I tried so many things.

This is my code for the moment:

```
class Eraser
{
    private Label status;
    private List<Rectangle> kaders;
    private List<TextBox> textboxen;
    private Canvas window;

    public Eraser(Canvas win, Label status)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.window = win;
        //Application.Current.MainWindow.Cursor  = new Cursor(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"../../Icons/eraser.cur");
        //Mouse.OverrideCursor = newCursor;
        //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Application.Current.MainWindow.Cursor;
        textboxen = new List<TextBox>();
        kaders = new List<Rectangle>();
        foreach (Object element in win.Children)
        {
            if (element is Rectangle)
            {
                Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, item_Mousedown);
                verzamelKaders();
            }
            else if (element is TextBox)
            {
                Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, Element_Mousedown);
                verzamelTextboxen();
            }
        }

    }
    private void verzamelKaders()
    {
        Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, item_Mousedown);

        foreach (Rectangle element in window.Children)
        {
            if (element.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
            {
                Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, item_Mousedown);
                kaders.Add(element);
                element.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Element_Mousedown);
            }
            else
            {
                element.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(item_Mousedown);
            }
        }

    }
    private void verzamelTextboxen()
    {

        Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, Element_Mousedown);


        foreach (TextBox item in window.Children)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, Element_Mousedown);
                textboxen.Add(item);
                item.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(item_Mousedown);
            }
            else
            {
                item.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Element_Mousedown);
            }

        }

    }
    private void Element_Mousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, item_Mousedown);
        Rectangle removekader = new Rectangle();
        removekader = (Rectangle)sender;
        window.Children.Remove(removekader);

    }
    private void item_Mousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Mouse.RemoveMouseDownHandler(window, Element_Mousedown);
        TextBox removeTextbox = new TextBox();
        removeTextbox = (TextBox)sender;
        window.Children.Remove(removeTextbox);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it so extremely complicated? The simple method below removes any child element from a Canvas at a specified position.

```
public static void RemoveChild(Canvas canvas, Point position)
{
    var element = canvas.InputHitTest(position) as UIElement;
    UIElement parent;

    while (element != null &&
        (parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement) != canvas)
    {
        element = parent;
    }

    if (element != null)
    {
        canvas.Children.Remove(element);
    }
}
```

You could call it in a `PreviewMouseDown` handler of your Canvas:

```
private void Canvas_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (eraseChildren)
    {
        var canvas = sender as Canvas;
        RemoveChild(canvas, e.GetPosition(canvas));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it was getting complicated for me 2. Just one thing, This piece of code is clean, Ty!